# preg_replace shortcode which may take one or two arguments

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to allow users to use a shortcode `[warning]` in the frontend of my site. This shortcode may be followed by only one `[warning](arg1)` or two arguments `[warning](optional-arg)(arg1)`.When the two arguments are entered the first one `optional-arg` will be considered as the heading and the second `arg1` as the body text and if only one is entered `arg1` it will be considered as the body text.

Here is the code I'm managing

```
function warning($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/\[warning\]\s*\((.*?)\)/', '<div class="alert alert-error"><div class="alert-content"> $1 </div></div>', $text); //for warning with body text only
    $text = preg_replace('/\[warning\]\s*\((.*?)\)\s*\((.*?)\)/', '<div class="alert alert-error"><div class="alert-content"><h2 class="alert-title"> $1 </h2><div class="alert-body"><p> $2 </p></div></div></div>', $text); //for warning with heading 
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'warning');
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'warning');
```

The problem is that the second argument is not considered and is out of the warning box.

Comment: once the `[warning]` has been replaced by the first `preg_replace`, it is not there anymore for the second `preg_replace` to take effect. You need either to test first if there are 2 parameters (switch the 2 lines if that works) or make the regex for 1 argument to not match the case when there are 2 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
function warning($text) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\[warning\]\s*\((.*?)\)(?:\s*\((.+?)\))?/', 
        function ($m) {
            if (isset($m[2])) {
                return '<div class="alert alert-error"><div class="alert-content"><h2 class="alert-title"> '.$m[1].' </h2><div class="alert-body"><p> '.$m[2].' </p></div></div></div>';
            } else {
                return '<div class="alert alert-error"><div class="alert-content"> '.$m[1].' </div></div>';
            }
        }
        , $text);
}
echo warning("[warning](body)"), "\n";
echo warning("[warning](header)(body)"), "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="alert alert-error"><div class="alert-content"> body </div></div>
<div class="alert alert-error"><div class="alert-content"><h2 class="alert-title"> header </h2><div class="alert-body"><p> body </p></div></div></div>
```